# How to detect email send/receive event and/or read content of email in Android?

Tags: android, email, permissions

Is it possible on Android device 2.1+ to get send/receive email event? Alternatively, is it possible to read the content of the single email in inbox?

I've tried with `content://com.android.email.provider/` with permission `com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER`, but it seems (`Not granting permission com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER`) it's not so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. 3rd party apps can't access the stock Email applications data.